# "python.exe can't find '__main__' module in ..." Error when trying to run python script opencv_blink_detect.py in virtual environment,

Tags: python, opencv, environment-variables, anaconda, virtualenv

Apologies if there's missing information. I'm using python for medical research and am trying to run a program to count the number of blinks via video footage.
https://github.com/skvrahul/blink_detect

[The script is located here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nzV0.png)

[My virtual environment is set up here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqcIc.png)

Package install instructions were followed from [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-and-dlib-on-windows-python-only/)

[Terminal open via Anaconda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYEQX.png)

[Attempt to run via readme instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye12y.png)

[Attempt to direct terminal to look at file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHYXt.png)

As you can see, the error message is

(opencv-env) C:\Users\wmj>python C:\Users\wmj\Documents\Python Scripts\Biometrics\blink_detect-master.py -p -sp.dat
C:\Users\wmj\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\opencv-env\python.exe: can't find '**main**' module in 'C:\Users\wmj\Documents\Python'

The contents of C:\Users\wmj\Documents\Python is just Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64

**I have searched online and most solutions to this problem seem to be either solved by modifying the .py file or doing something with Pycharm**

*What is the solution to this? I want to be able to run the script as a demonstration to my supervisor*

Thank you,

WW

Answer (score 0):

Try first to cd to the exact location of the package and then run exactly as written in the readme instructions. 
Python has to get the full path of the script you're trying to execute and the script itself has to get the `sp.dat` file as an argument.